# SQL Server PAAS Implementation with Mirroring

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-sync

There is a requirement in our project to maintain the same copy of one database across different geographies with asynchronous/synchronous update whenever the database is updated in one geography. How can this be achieved using Azure PAAS SQL Server database? Please note that, at all times all the instances should be up and running.

Comment: There is a detailed article on HA for SQL DB [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-designing-cloud-solutions-for-disaster-recovery), but really this question is too broad and should be closed.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, we are maintaining regions not for high availability and all the regions should be up and running all the time. It is basically to reduce latency. I need a solution on the same.

Comment: Active geo-replication, (described and linked to in that article) offers the ability to offload read-only workloads to up to four readable secondaries in multiple regions ie offers what you are asking for via a HA solution.  Are you saying you don't want your databases to be highly-available?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [SQL Data Sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync), where you can define a hub database and many member databases located on different regions. The synchronization can be one-way or bi-directional, and occurs when you schedule it to happen. Databases involved in the subscription do not need to belong to the same subscription.

You can also use [Azure Geo-Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-geo-replication-overview) to replicate databases to other regions (but recommended to be a [paired region](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/best-practices-availability-paired-regions)), and secondary databases are only readable, with asynchronous synchronization occurring automatically. Databases need to be on the same subscription. Azure Geo-Replication is based on the AlwaysOn technology of SQL Server to asynchronously replicate committed transactions on a primary database to a secondary database using read committed snapshot isolation (RCSI).